# ReadAsAsync - Error : "Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have the below code that gets an object from the web api service.

At the following line of code

```
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CMLandingPage>().Result;
```

I get the following exception :

`InnerException = {"Could not create an instance of type MLSReports.Models.IMetaData. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'BaBrInfo.Series[0].name', line 1, position 262."}`

Any pointers are much appreciated.

```
 CMLandingPage lpInfo = new CMLandingPage();

            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Add an Accept header for JSON format
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(LPChartinfoapiURL, criteria.Mlsnums).Result;
                }
                // Throw exception if not a success code.
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                // Parse the response body.
                lpInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CMLandingPage>().Result;
                }
```

CMLandingPage  :

```
namespace MLSReports.Models
{
    public class CMLandingPage
    {
        public CMLandingPage()  {  }

        public CMColumn BaBrInfo { get; set; }

     }
  public class CMColumnItem<T> : IMetaData
    {
        #region Constructors and Methods
        public CMColumnItem()   {   }
        #endregion

        #region Properties and Fields
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<T> data { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        #endregion

    }

    public class CMColumn
    {
        #region Constructor and Method
        public CMColumn()
        {
           Series = new List<IMetaData>();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties and Fields
        public string ChartType { get; set; }
        public string ChartTitle { get; set; }
        public List<IMetaData> Series { get; set; }
        #endregion    
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the deserializer figure out a concrete type to use to make your Series??

Comment: If you case is more advanced and you need more fine grained control over your deserialization then maybe take a look at creating a MediaTypeFormatter. ReadAsAsync accepts them.

Comment: I have the same issue, and the deserializer should be able to figure out the concrete type because the json returned contains "$type" : "A.B.C, C"

Comment: I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147045/type-is-an-interface-or-abstract-class-and-cannot-be-instantiated-c-sharp-send. 

Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CmColumn` class has this property on it:

```
    public List<IMetaData> Series { get; set; }
```

The WebApi controller is evidently trying to construct an object based on the values of the parameters you're sending it. When it gets to the value with the name "BaBrInfo.Series[0].name", it knows it should create a new `IMetaData` object so that it can set its `name` and add it to the `Series` property, but `IMetaData` is just an interface: it doesn't know what type of object to construct.

Try changing `IMetaData` to some concrete type that implements that interface.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the serializer to include the type in the json payload and the deserializer to use the included type:

```
//Serialization
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dto, config);

//Deserialization
var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    SerializerSettings = { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }
};
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CMLandingPage>(new [] { formatter }).Result;
```

[POLYMORPHIC SERIALIZATION USING NEWTON JSON.NET IN HTTPCONTENT](https://kirmir.com/2014/05/16/polymorphic-serialization-using-newton-json-net-in-httpcontent/)

Comment: +1 This may not have really addressed all the issues the OP had (though, it may have), but it's more complete than a lot of associated questions: the types need to be included when serializing, and when deserializing json.net doesn't use those type names unless you overload the formatter.