# Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. c# send a object with contain a list of abstract object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest

I have an abstract superClass "*Publication*" that has two derived classes *Auction* and *Purchase*. Also I have a class *category* that has a list of Publications.

In my Rest Server side I send the a list of Category, in the client side I receive this list of Category and try to cast the object as a list of Categories. The problem is when I try to cast the object I get the follow error :

> Could not create an instance of type FrontOffice.Models.Publication. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].Publications[0].Price'

I will paste below of this, the code that I am using.

```
 //Rest Server Controller
 public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategory() {
     return listCategory;
 }

//Category Class
public class Category {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
}

//Publication Entity
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Auction))]
[KnownType(typeof(Buyout))]
public abstract class Publication {
    [DataMember]
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Publication() {}

    public Publication(int PublicationID, string Title, string Description) {
        this.PublicationID = PublicationID;
        this.Title = Title;
    }
}
```

And in the client side I do :

```
List<Category> listCategory = new List<Category>();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50687/");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/categories/GetAllcategory").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    listCategory = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Category>>().Result;
}
```

I am getting the error in the line that I try to instance listCategory.

Comment: You may want to have a look at what is in the `InnerExceptions` of your `AggregateException` to find out more, and add this information to your question.

Comment: Unless you put more information about the exception no one will be able to help you. Post the full stack trace and InnerException

Comment: `AggregateException` is just a list of several (although often, honestly, just one) exceptions. As Alex mentioned, you need to inspect the `InnerExceptions` (note the trailing 's') property from that to be able to find what actually caused the exception. This is essentially just saying "you've received an error," and without those details (which VS will readily tell you), that's impossible to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an `AggregateException` is because you are calling an async method (`ReadAsAsync`):

```
listCategory = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Category>>().Result;
```

In async code, you can (sort of) run multiple parallel lines of code. Any one of these lines of code can throw an exception, and due to this nature, async methods that throw exceptions will throw an `AggregateException`. The purpose of this exception is to collect, or aggregate, all of the exceptions that could have been thrown by "parallel" lines of code.

However as @Matthew Haugen points out, 99% of your AggregateExceptions will just wrap a single exception. What you have to do is

1. find the exception that is wrapped inside it, and
2. either figure out why *that* exception is being thrown, or post it in your question and ask for more help.

Bottom line is that the problem could be one of many things in your code, and more information is needed to solve it. Since the exception happens only when `Category.Publications` is not null, I wonder are you using EntityFramework with lazy loading? If so, it could be an issue with the foreign key between Category and Publication. But that's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: The problem is because the definitions of entities are circular. I mean publication has  a list of categories, and categories has a list of Publications

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo since you never posted the code for your `Publication` class, there was no way to tell this. But it does make sense. Sounds like you should instead return a viewmodel without circular references from the API action (like `IEnumerable<CategoryApiModel>`).

Comment: I add the code of publications, and the inner exception "Could not create an instance of type FrontOffice.Models.Publication. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].Publications[0].Price', line 1, position 57."